# I want to add secondary axis in pivot chart in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, pivot-table, legend

I have a pivot chart i.e. bar graph chart report (dashboard) with report names in vertical axis and horizontal has average of values (duration in secs) per date (this value will be updated daily), date is filter.  I want to plot benchmark value (its duration in sec i.e. static value for every report in horizontal axis) on graph against every report.

I added benchmark value in values, legend fields, but the value is average hence only value against which benchmark is present is displayed on graph.